# How to add developers list to maven generated site?

Tags: java, maven-2

I have just started using maven and have question. 
My pom.xml contains tag "developer" with the full details of the team. What should I do to make this list visible on my project site? I know how to add a menu item to site.xml. But where this item should refer?

I found only one project in Jakarata that does it: the maven itself. They have tag developers in pom and link "The Maven Team" on site. This link refers to team-list.html. I have downloaded the full maven source and ran "mvn site" but this file was not generated on my environment and grepping the files did not help too.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Listing the developers should be enough to get them on the generated site (i.e., it works for me) so whatever is wrong is something not very obvious. Check out your effective POM to see what's actually being used to drive the generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it has always been the case but it appears the **Project Team** report (`team-list.html`) should get generated by default during `mvn site` and be available under the **Project Information**. I just tested that on a sample project and it does work as expected.

If it doesn't, maybe try to configure the `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` explicitly to generate the report.

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>index</report>
              <report>project-team</report>
              ...
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

Are you using a particular version of the maven site plugin? What version of Maven exactly?

Comment: No, this report is run by default.  But if you don't have any developers listed in the pom you don't get the report.

Comment: @Jon The OP **does** have developer listed as he wrote in his question. But thanks for your great input.

Comment: @Jon I'll rephrase my answer but it appears that the OP does NOT get the default behavior. Which is the whole point of the question. But nevermind.

Answer (score 4):

the `mvn site` command should work and your POM should look something like the following:

```
...
    <!-- List the core committers -->
    <developers>
      <developer>
        <id>karianna</id>
        <name>Martijn Verburg</name>
        <organization>Ikasan</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://www.ikasan.org</organizationUrl>
        <roles>
          <role>developer</role>
        </roles>
        <timezone>0</timezone>
      </developer>
      ...
    </developers>

    <!-- Contributors -->
    <contributors>
        <contributor>
            <name>Cae Fernandes</name>
            <roles>
                <role>developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>-3</timezone>
        </contributor>
        ...
     </contributors>
...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have. Now I want to write tag 
      <item name="The Team" href="???"/> and the question is what do I have to write instead of question marks?

Comment: Is the team page not coming up for you automatically?